# How does stackoverflow make its Tag input field?

Tags: html, input, tags

How does StackOverflow create its tag system. How can it format the html in a text area?

I just don't know where to begin. If someone could guide me, then I can know what direction to take so I can write some code that someone can check.

**Like this:**

[image]

**EDIT:
Basically, when I press space, how do i add a new element/div to the inside of the div?**

Comment: I've made a solid, lightweight one - https://github.com/yairEO/tagify

Comment: @vsync's seems pretty good. I like [Selectize](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) even better.

Comment: @JasonSwett - what do you like in **Selectize** that would make you choose a 85kb (js only) lib over an ~8kb lib? the ease of flexibility of **tagify** is very good (CSS is very short, flexiable and well-ordered)

Comment: @vsync Because I like its UI better.

Comment: @vsync tagify is a great tool. Thanks for that. I would even suggest it for an answer even it is not an answer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What I would do is:

- Create a master DIV with a border (like here the border 1px solid #000)
- After, inside this DIV, I will create another DIV (float: left;), another DIV (float: right) and an input inside the right div.

When you write inside the input and let's say you select HTML, it creates a span in the left DIV and reduces the width of the right div to match the remaining size. Of course, inside your span there's the text HTML with the delete sign.

You could do it easily using jQuery.

Example:

```
<div id="master_div">
    <div id="categories">

    </div>
    <div id="input">
        <input type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And you write some jQuery / JS

Comment: +1: Additional information: Pressing backspace will result in the last added tag being deleted.

Comment: https://github.com/tovic/tags-input-beautifier ← pure JavaScript, with the same concept. Pressing _backspace_ will remove the last child node.

Answer (score 28):

What about Bootstrap solution?

You can try this :

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" value="html,input,tag" data-role="tagsinput"></input>
```

For CSS, call these two files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">
```

For Javascript, call these two files:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
```

The code will generate the result below:

[image]

**### Check it out.**

Comment: FWIW, this library isn't part of Bootstrap. It's a third-party library that apparently uses Bootstrap.

Comment: Unfortunately unmaintained. This library isn't: http://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/

Comment: This library uses older bootstrap versions (2.3.2 and 3) and not maintained properly, most probably would not run in newer versions unless you make huge edits in source code, found a better solution here : https://codepen.io/curthusting/pen/FLhpE.

Comment: @Jad Chahine - Clean & neat. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't. If you look at the DOM, you see initially just an input box. Once you add a tag, it inserts a `<span>` tag before the input box with that tag and it's delete icon. The input box is now to the right of this `<span>` tag. When you click on a tag to edit it, it puts a textbox in its place so you can edit it. All this is done with Javascript and there are some JQuery plugins to help you do this. Here's one from a quick Google search: http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

As far as styling goes, the `<span>` elements can have whatever CSS you want on them.

Answer (score 6):

```js
var es = document.querySelectorAll('.input-categories');
for (var i = 0; i < es.length; i++) {
  es[i]._list = es[i].querySelector('ul');
  es[i]._input = es[i].querySelector('input');
  es[i]._input._icategories = es[i];
  es[i].onkeydown = function(e){
    var e = event || e;
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
      var c = e.target._icategories;
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = c._input.value;
      c._list.appendChild(li);
      c._input.value = '';
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.input-categories{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.input-categories ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.input-categories li{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 1px;
}
.input-categories input{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-categories">
  <ul>
    <li>moscow</li>
    <li>new york</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text"/>
</div>

<div class="input-categories">
  <ul>
    <li>CSS</li>
    <li>PHP</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you did to make this answer more useful for future readers?

Answer (score 0):

### React functional component

```
const AutoList=()=>{
const [currentTagText, setCurrentTagText] = useState("");
const [tags, setTags] = useState(["javascript"]);

const handleTag = (e) => {
   setCurrentTagText(e.target.value);
   if (e.keyCode == 13 && currentTagText) {
    setTags((prevTags) => [...prevTags, currentTagText]);
    setCurrentTagText("");
   } else if (e.keyCode == 32 && currentTagText) {
    setTags((prevTags) => [...prevTags, currentTagText]);
    setCurrentTagText("");
   }
};
const removeTag = (index) => {
   const newTagArray = tags;
   newTagArray.splice(index, 1);
   setTags([...newTagArray]);
};

return (

  <div className="masterStackDiv">
          <div
            className="stackTags"
            style={{ display: tags.length > 0 ? "flex" : "none" }}
          >
            {tags.map((tag) => {
              return (
              <div className="stackTag">
                 <button
                    onClick={() => removeTag(index)}
                    className="tagCloseBtn"
                  >
                    x
                  </button>
                  #{tag}
              </div>
               )
            })}
          </div>
          <div className="stackInput">
            <input
              type="text"
              onKeyDown={handleTag}
              onChange={handleTag}
              value={currentTagText}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
 )

}
```

CSS:-

```
.masterStackDiv {
  width: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.stackInput input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  font-size: 0.8em;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.stackTag {
  background-color: #707070;
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.stackTags {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
}
.tagCloseBtn {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.tagCloseBtn:hover {
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```js
const {useState} = React
 
const StackTag=()=>{
 const [currentTagText, setCurrentTagText] = useState("");
 const [tags, setTags] = useState(["javascript"]);
 
 const handleTag = (e) => {
    setCurrentTagText(e.target.value);
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && currentTagText) {
      setTags((prevTags) => [...prevTags, currentTagText]);
      setCurrentTagText("");
    } else if (e.keyCode == 32 && currentTagText) {
      setTags((prevTags) => [...prevTags, currentTagText]);
      setCurrentTagText("");
    }
  };
  
  const removeTag = (index) => {
    const newTagArray = tags;
    newTagArray.splice(index, 1);
    setTags([...newTagArray]);
  };

  return (
       <div className="masterStackDiv">
              <div
                className="stackTags"
                style={{ display: tags.length > 0 ? "flex":"none"}} 
              >
                {tags.map((tag, index) => {
                  return (
                    <div className="stackTag" key={index}>
                      <button
                        onClick={() => removeTag(index)}
                        className="tagCloseBtn"
                      >
                        x
                      </button>
                      #{tag}
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
              <div className="stackInput">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  onKeyDown={handleTag}
                  onChange={handleTag}
                  value={currentTagText}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            )
       }
ReactDOM.render(<StackTag/>,document.getElementById("react"))
```

```css
.masterStackDiv {
  width: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.stackInput input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  font-size: 0.8em;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.stackTag {
  background-color: #707070;
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.stackTags {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
}
.tagCloseBtn {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.tagCloseBtn:hover {
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="react"></div>
</body>
</html>
```