# Make a text clearable with a close button on click of Submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, autocomplete

I need to implement a code in jquery, where I can enter any text in the text field, and then after I click on the "Submit" button, that text should turn into a clearable field something like this[image]

I tried putting this box in my textfield, but this makes my whole text field as a clearable field,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=text]').clearableTextField();
  });
```

I dont want to do this, I want that when i type something in the text field and click the Submit button, it should become a clearable text object. 
Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: `$('form').submit(fucntion(){$('#inputId').val('');}); `

Comment: I dont want to clear the field :) I want to make the text clearable with a close button on submit. Please see the attachemnt that I have attached with the post.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this (similar to the way tag entry is done on Stack Overflow) is to have a separate div to the left of your input field into which "clearable text fields" are placed.  When the submit button is clicked (or the spacebar is hit, or any trigger that javascript can listen for), have javascript create a new `span` within the left `div`, and reduce the width of the input field by the same width as the new `span` tag.  You can include a delete button and any relevant styling in the HTML/CSS for the `span`.

A demo which achieves a similar effect through jQuery is available here: http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/. (Suggested by @sachleen in response to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839570/how-does-stackoverflow-make-its-tag-input-field))