# Border is not coming properly in div css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a tag like input system, but running in issues with css.

What I am expecting is that green color should border and wrap the 2 divs inside it but it is not. Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqh5ngq4/).

This is the link I am following to create the tag like system https://stackoverflow.com/a/10839632/639406

My code -

```
<div class="master" style="border: 1px solid #3ef001; width: 200px;">
    <div class="tagCont" style="float: left;">
        <span>HTML</span>
        <span>CSS</span>
        <span>PHP</span>
    </div>

    <div class="inputElem" style="float: right;">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Apart from just a solution, I am looking for where I am wrong with the concept as I am not very good with CSS part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to want to add `display:inline-block;` to your `.master` div in order for the border to function how you want.

```
<div class="master" style="border: 1px solid #3ef001; width: 200px; display:inline-block;">
    <div class="tagCont" style="float: left;">
        <span>HTML</span>
        <span>CSS</span>
        <span>PHP</span>
    </div>

    <div class="inputElem" style="float: right;">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m3shyss6/

As far as concept is concerned, you're having issues because the div is not taking on the size of its contents. changing its display property to `inline-block` allows for this to happen.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a [clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/):

https://jsfiddle.net/aqh5ngq4/1/

```css
.master::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="master" style="border: 1px solid #3ef001; width: 200px;">
  <div class="tagCont" style="float: left;">
    <span>HTML</span>
    <span>CSS</span>
    <span>PHP</span>
  </div>

  <div class="inputElem" style="float: right;">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```