# FIlter is not happening in html list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating one list on click of input tag. Now I want to be filter data while typing on the input tag and taht is happening, but after selecting one data the filteration is not happening from the second data onwards.

Code for my filter.

```
function filterList(value, list) {
        var li, i, match;

        for (i = list.children.length; i--;) {
            li = list.children[i];
            match = li.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            li.classList.toggle('hidden', !match)
        }
    }
```

Here are few problem I am facing. Can anybody help me to resolve this. I created a fiddler where things are working and you can see problem.. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arsenal/kLaeyt5L/)

1. Filter is not happening for second data onwards.
2. Once place some data from key and then select some value from list, both value is coming.

Answer (score 2):

you added a space between quotes

`li[i].style.display = " ";`

so just remove that space it will work fine

```
li[i].style.display = "";
```

---

as you are planning to add selected fields in the input field 
( `which is some thing like how you add tags in stackoverflow` or some other sites )

you can find similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839570/how-does-stackoverflow-make-its-tag-input-field) 
and read comments there, as some one mentioned libraries linked to [GitHub](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify)

Comment: No That is not a problem at all. When type after selecting first value, this will give you value as `old selected value + new typed value.`

Comment: Wondering what is image have to do there. Well I remove that but result is same.

Comment: great hack, but selection itself is not happening right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147610/discussion-between-bhv-and-david).

Answer (score 0):

Well... let's just say you have a lot of problems with the code.

First of all, keep your console on at all times.

```
for (i = list.children.length; i--;) {
    li = list.children[i];
    match = li.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    li.classList.toggle('hidden', !match)
}
```

Your `for` loop starts outside of the array index already. Not to mention you put the step part in the conditional part.

Using a `for.. of` instead works so much better in this case.

Secondly, you're applying a class to the li that has no effect because you haven't defined it in the css.

Thirdly, I'm not sure why you're putting the showing/hiding logic inside the openingList function, makes no sense.

```
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = " ";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Here's a working/updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/kLaeyt5L/2/

Comment: Sir, Even in updated fiddle When I select United State, then I type AF to filter Afganistan but its not happening.

Comment: @David Tbh, your code and question is so clumsy I'm not even sure what you're trying to do beyond having a searchable filter that works

Comment: @A.Lau Thanks for answer but searchable filter is not working after select first data.

Comment: @David You're going to need to word your question better and format your code better if you expect people to solve this problem.