# How to make a textbox which can accept tags like stackoverflow tag selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I like to make a text box which can be searchable and can select or remove multiple tags and finally submit it to database. 
Something like this in stackoverflow:
[image]

I tried using this:

```
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Where is your javascript code?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a plugin like this:

https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Comment: How can restrict the input only from a list of values?

Comment: You can check it in the documentation, the source parameter makes the trick: `$('input').tagsinput({
  itemValue: 'value',
  itemText: 'text',
  source: function(query) {
    return [{ "value": 1 , "text": "Amsterdam"  }, { "value": 2 , "text": "Madrid"  }];
  }
});`

Comment: Hi this is 5years future time traveler here. I have checked the npm package, it is made for Bootstrap 2 and 3, but I am using 5. Is there a new npm package for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this JQuery plugin](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="css/jquery.tagit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/tag-it.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<ul id="myTags">
    <!-- Existing list items will be pre-added to the tags -->
    <li>Tag1</li>
    <li>Tag2</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myTags").tagit();
    });

    $("#myTags").tagit({
        availableTags: ["c++", "java", "php", "javascript", "ruby", "python", "c"],
    readOnly: true,    
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How can restrict the input only from a list of values?

Comment: $("#myTags").tagit({
    availableTags: ["c++", "java", "php", "javascript", "ruby", "python", "c"]
});

Comment: @qwww see this light documentation of it https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown

Comment: @qwww I add an example for you. Plz try it and give me your feedback

Comment: I tried it..its not working may be due to some collision with my css

Answer (score 1):

This might help specifically about Stack Overflow's tag selection ->
[Stack Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839570/how-does-stackoverflow-make-its-tag-input-field) as well as using frameworks like [bootstrap](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) could make this much easier for you like already mentioned.

Comment: How can restrict the input only from a list of values?

Comment: Okay so what you can do is have a disable input as well as a dropdown where the list of views are in the dropdown. when a view is selected from the dropdown it is removed from the dropdown and added as a tag in the input field. When the tag is removed from the input field it is then added again to the dropdown. Are you using any frameworks?

Comment: I am working on flask framework