# Rails Tagging with autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, jquery-chosen, tagging

I'm trying to complete this article about tagging
https://medium.com/@sherzelsmith/add-a-filtering-multiple-tag-system-with-autocomplete-to-your-rails-model-in-rails-5-1bf88cd53e9

 My problem is that I need to make creation of non-existing possible, but for now it clears the field if you are trying to fill it with new tag (non-existing at the moment) so no new tag can be created by this method.
The author of this article deployed a demo of this feature, so I'll leave it here for better understanding of what I'm talking about.
https://blogit-ss.herokuapp.com/posts/new

```
<div class = 'col-md-8 offset-2'>
  <h1 class = "text-center">New Tag</h1>
  <%= simple_form_for @product, url: product_path(@product) do |f| %>
    <p><small>Tags: <%= raw @product.tags.map(&:name).map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %></small</p>
    <p><%= f.input :tag_ids, collection: Tag.order(:name), include_blank: true, input_html: { multiple: true, class: 'chosen-select' } %></p>
    <%= f.submit "Next", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

So maybe someone here have any suggestions of how to avoid 'no results match' and let the form to accept new tags? Like it works here, on Stackoverflow.

 The only way that was the nearest to my goal - text_field in form_for: 

<%= f.text_field :tag_list, collection: Tag.order(:name), include_blank: true, input_html: { multiple: true, class: 'chosen-select' } %>


which allows typing tag names separated with commas, but without autocomplete.

Comment: So you simply want to add your own tag instead of selecting from the list

Comment: Well, technically, yes, it should allow adding new tags (hence creating db record on Tag model)

Comment: Okay let me try this

Comment: Thanks. Here you can find author's demo-project repository
https://github.com/snsmith92/blogit

Comment: @mayan I have replied to your problem solution if it works for you please mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the best solution for this one is covered in Jad Chahine's answer to similar problem

 https://stackoverflow.com/a/36350998/10253611

Simply adding **bootstrap-tagsinput** library to my project and passing **data-role** to my input field (although for now it is without autocomplete, but good for start):

```
<div class = 'col-md-8 offset-2'>
  <h1 class = 'text-center'>New Blog Post</h1>
  <%= simple_form_for @product, url: tag_link_product_url(@product), remote: true do |f| %>
  <p><small id='tag_links'>Tags: <%= raw @product.tags.order(:name).map { |tag| link_to tag.name, products_path(q: { tags_id_eq: tag.id }) }.join(', ') %></small</p>
  <%= f.text_field :tag_list, collection: Tag.order(:name), 'data-role': 'tagsinput', input_html: { multiple: true, class: 'chosen-select' } %>
  <%= f.submit "Next", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have added another taggable drop down This is the working link

[Working link for add customizable tag](https://b45f757e.ngrok.io)

And below is the link for code on GitHub

[Github link for the customizable drop down code](https://github.com/swazruby786/customizeable-dropdown)

Comment: Thanks for a try, but it contains over 1.8k(!) lines of code which is not suitable for my purpose. So I will continue the search. But again, thanks anyway.

Comment: Okay @MaryanYurchylyak